# automatically scrolling to a specific pageview when a button is pressed in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a horizontal list of 10 containers wrapped using PageView builder.

PageView.builder(
controller: _pageController,
itemCount: items.length,
itemBuilder:
(BuildContext context, int index) {
return ContainerItem(index);
},
),
I have another button which on pressing, should scroll the containers to get to that specific container. How do I achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Using your `PageController` you can achieve this, the purpose of the controller is to control so....
This is what you are looking for:

```
_pageController.animateToPage(
  index,
  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
  curve: Curves.easeInOut,
);
```

`index` is the page to want to scroll to, from 0 to the (items.length - 1). If you have 3 items, then setting `index` to 0 will represent the first...and so on

Look at the docs: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageController-class.html